# Trying to connect ASPNET Core WebAPI to new Ubuntu Server 22.04 Database for an Angular Project

Tags: mysql, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ubuntu

I know this has been asked a few times on these boards so I am sorry to post another one. Also, this is my first time posting so I'm nervous but mostly, I am so confused.  I have an Angular 16 frontend website that uses ASPNET.Core 7 backend which **USED **to connect to a MSSQL database locally. I have recently purchased a server and I'm trying to get it running.

```
Server is Ubuntu: 22.04
Database: mysql 8
EntityFrameworkCore version 6
ASP.NET Core 7
```

Everything worked great locally.

- Do I still use Cors() in my Program.cs?

Program.cs file:

```
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ??       throw new InvalidOperationException();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ItemDetailContext>(options =>     options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            
            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            //ANGULAR
            builder.Services.AddCors();
            var configuration = builder.Configuration;

            var app = builder.Build();

            //ANGULAR
            app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
```

Per tutorials, I commented out **bind-address**

````
    $ grep 'bind-address' vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
    /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:#bind-address = 0.0.0.0```
````

```
    $ sudo systemctl status mysql
    ●  mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: **active** (running) since Sun 2023-07-30 03:02:40 UTC; 2min 2s ago
```

I am using csf, not ufw:

```
    $ grep 3306 /etc/csf/csf.conf
    TCP_IN = "3306"
    TCP_OUT = "3306"
    UDP_IN = "3306"
    UDP_OUT = "3306"
```

appsettings.json:

```
    $ grep -i 'defaultconnection' appsettings.json
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;User Id=<mysql user>;Password=<password>;Database=   <datebasename"
```

The dotnet ef migration add InitialCreate works fine.
When I get to updating the database:

```
    $ dotnet ef database update
    Build started...
    Build succeeded.
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error      occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not     accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow     remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server:     Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean     breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj,     Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds      connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,    Boolean withFailover)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo,    String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer    timeout, Boolean withFailover)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo,   String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout,    SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String   newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String   accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions     options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,    DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,  DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,   DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection  owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions,  DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,    DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Thank you in advance if you can help or show me another thread. I've been through so many though already.

[UPDATE]: I never ran Publish on the application. That MIGHT be it.

Comment: Which tutorial did you use? Databases usually are not directly reachable from the internet, as the firewall would block such potential dangerous connections. You should find a tutorial that explains REST API for you

Comment: You are right. I forgot about that when I did learn (briefly) about REST. I know in the real world, it's best to have a server dedicated to databases, but this is just a test server, however, I do want to show employers and that's a good security measure to take. This at least gives me something to search around for. I appreciate your help.